# how to fix the date regex?

Tags: java, regex, spring, string, date

I'm trying to use the regex only for the `dd/MM/yyyy` date format but if I enter the `dd/MM/yy` value it accepts. I would like to know how to make it accept only the `dd/MM/yyyy` values.

If I use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(value);
```

the code continues to accept `dd/MM/yy` format.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "10/02/20";
                    
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([0-2][0-9]||3[0-1])/(0[0-9]||1[0-2])/([0-9][0-9])?[0-9][0-9]$");
                        
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
            
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask questions in English here or ask on [Stackoverflow Portugues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). By the way, why are you trying to reformat a date `String` with a regular expression? You could use a `java.time.LocalDate` and suitable `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`s.

Comment: I tried to use but still accept the value dd / mm / yyyy

Comment: You need a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uu").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);`, which would accept two-digit years only.

Comment: DateTimeFormatter withResolverStyle = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
       .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

     LocalDate.parse(value, withResolverStyle);

Comment: One thing: Don't use `y` for the year, it means year-of-era and can cause trouble in situations where the era is not implicitly definite. Use `u`. Otherwise: Glad it helped, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Define the format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        String dateString;
        LocalDate date = null;
        boolean valid;

        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter a date in dd/MM/yyyy format: ");
            dateString = scanner.nextLine();
            try {
                // Try to parse the input string
                date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid format");
                // Set `valid` to false in case of exception
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);// Loop as long as valid is false

        System.out.println("Date in ISO-8601 format: " + date);
        System.out.println("Date in dd/MM/yyyy format: " + date.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a date in dd/MM/yyyy format: 09/09/20
Invalid format
Enter a date in dd/MM/yyyy format: 09/09/2020
Date in ISO-8601 format: 2020-09-09
Date in dd/MM/yyyy format: 09/09/2020
```

**Regex Solution:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String dateString;
        boolean valid;
        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter a date in dd/MM/yyyy format: ");
            dateString = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!dateString.matches("\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid format");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);// Loop as long as valid is false
        System.out.println(dateString);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a date in dd/MM/yyyy format: 09/09/20
Invalid format
Enter a date in dd/MM/yyyy format: 09/09/2020
09/09/2020
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `\d` specifies a digit
2. `X{n}` [speciifies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) `X, exactly n times`